# Can I force NSTextField to use ASCII quotes instead of unicode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an NSTextField to collect a format string, which is used to create some text that is then saved to a file. If I enter double quotes (") in the NSTextField, the string from NSTextField.stringValue is encoded as 0xe2 0x80 0x9d, which is unicode for double quotes. If I try to save the resulting string to a file, using NSASCIIStringEncoding, it complains that the encoding fails. Can I force NSTextEdit to use the ASCII character for double quotes, 0x22? I've tried lossy conversion:

[NSString dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding
       allowLossyConversion: YES]

but its solution is to remove the quote altogether.

I've tried changing the "Use smart quotes and dashes" setting in System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Text

Answer (score 2):

While an `NSTextField` is being edited, it has an `NSTextView` subview that handles the actual editing. This subview is called the “field editor”.

`NSTextView` has an `automaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled` property. You want to turn this off for the field editor.

You can do this by creating a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell` and overriding the `setUpFieldEditorAttributes` method. In Swift:

```
class MyTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

    override func setUpFieldEditorAttributes(_ textObj: NSText) -> NSText {
        super.setUpFieldEditorAttributes(textObj)
        if let textView = textObj as? NSTextView {
            textView.isAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = false
        }
        return textObj
    }

}
```

In your xib, select the cell of your text field and set its custom class to `MyTextFieldCell`.

By default, each window has a single field editor shared by all text fields in the window. So using this custom cell subclass will have the effect of leaving smart quotes turned off for all text fields in that window after that one text field has had keyboard focus. If that's not what you want, then you need to use a separate field editor just for the one text field that you want to be free of smart quotes.

To use a separate field editor for the special text field, you have two choices:

- Create an `NSWindow` subclass. In the subclass, override `fieldEditor:forObject:` to return a separate `NSTextView` for the fields where you want to disable smart quotes, and return `[super fieldEditor:createFlag forObject:object]` for normal field.
- Give your window a delegate (if it doesn't have one already). In the delegate, implement `windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:` to return a separate `NSTextView` if the field (the `client` argument) should have smart quotes disabled. Return nil for other fields.

If you go with a separate-field-editor solution, you probably don't have to use a custom `NSTextFieldCell` subclass. You can just set the special field editor's `isAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled` to false before returning it.

Comment: I tried two variants of what you suggest (space restricts to first):
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
            TextEditorNoAQSub = [[NSTextView alloc] init];  // Controller class member of NSTextView*
        TextEditorNoAQSub.automaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = NO;
    }

    - (id) windowWillReturnFieldEditor: (NSWindow*) sender
                              toObject: (id) client
    {
        return TextViewEditorNoAutoQuoteSub;
    }

The edit behavior changes (text disappears on <return>), but the ASCII encoding still fails.

Comment: Second variant:
`
    - (id) windowWillReturnFieldEditor: (NSWindow*) sender
                          toObject: (id) client
{
    if (client == TextFieldOutputFormat) {
        NSText* defaultFieldEditor = [myWindow fieldEditor: NO
                                                 forObject: nil];
        
        if ([defaultFieldEditor isKindOfClass: [NSTextView class]] == YES) {
            NSTextView* defaultFieldEdAsTV = (NSTextView*) defaultFieldEditor;
            
            defaultFieldEdAsTV.automaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = NO;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
`